# How to mitigate privilege escalation in Docker Containers to secure the host FS

Tags: security, docker, virtualization

A question on secuity. I want to allow non-root users to deploy containers on say a cluster, I'd be concerned if they could mount host directories and then escalate to root privileges inside the container. I gather from the articles below that the feature for mapping a container-root-user to a host-non-root-user is still in the ether? The article itself seems to be relatively old, I'm curious to know how developed these features are.

> "Recent improvements in Linux namespaces will soon allow to run
>   full-featured containers without root privileges, thanks to the new
>   user namespace. This is covered in detail here. Moreover, this will
>   solve the problem caused by sharing filesystems between host and
>   guest, since the user namespace allows users within containers
>   (including the root user) to be mapped to other users in the host
>   system.
>
> The end goal for Docker is therefore to implement two additional
>   security improvements:
>
> 1) map the root user of a container to a non-root user of the Docker
>   host, to mitigate the effects of a container-to-host privilege
>   escalation;
>
> 2) allow the Docker daemon to run without root privileges,
>   and delegate operations requiring those privileges to well-audited
>   sub-processes, each with its own (very limited) scope: virtual network
>   setup, filesystem management, etc.

https://docs.docker.com/articles/security/
http://blog.docker.com/2013/08/containers-docker-how-secure-are-they/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I gather from the articles below that the feature for mapping a container-root-user to a host-non-root-user is still in the ether?

The article "[User namespaces have arrived in Docker!](http://integratedcode.us/2015/10/13/user-namespaces-have-arrived-in-docker/)" ([Phil Estes](https://github.com/estesp), [ESTESP](http://integratedcode.us/author/estesp/)), illustrates it is not in the ehter anymore!
It [will be available in the experimental branch of docker 1.9](https://twitter.com/icecrime/status/652916718902226944?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) (Nov. 2014). [PR 12648](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12648).

The user mapping is confirmed:

> One of the **most important features of user namespaces is that it allows containers to have a different view of the uid and gid ranges than the host system.**
>   Specifically, a process (and in our case, the process(es) inside our container) can be provided a set of mappings from the host uid and gid space, such that when the process thinks it is running as uid 0 (commonly known as “`root`”), it may actually be running as uid 1000, or 10000, or even 34934322.  It all depends on the mappings we provide when we create the process inside a user namespace.
>
> Of course, it should be clear that from a security perspective this is a great feature as **it allows our containers to continue running with root privileges, but without actually having any root privilege on the host**.

See more at the "[Experimental: User namespace support](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/userns.md)" documentation page (for an [experimental docker build](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/experimental), from [experimental.docker.com](https://experimental.docker.com/)) .

```
docker daemon --userns-remap=default
```

Note that some of standard Docker features are currently incompatible when running a Docker daemon with experimental user namespaces enabled, like sharing namespaces with the host (`--pid=host`, `--net=host`, etc.) or with other containers.

**That user mapping ability is for now per-daemon, not yet per container** (that would require a Linux kernel evolution which be in the work, but not).
sharing namespaces with the host (--pid=host, --net=host, etc.)

Finally:

> Due to the need to segregate content in the Docker daemon’s local cache of layer data by the mappings provided, once you use an experimental build with user namespaces, **the root of your graph directory (`/var/lib/docker` by default) will have one additional level of indirection which correlates to the remapped root uid and gid**.
>
> For example, if the remapping user I provide to the `--userns-remap` flag has subordinate user and group ranges that begin with ID `10000`, then the root of the graph directory for all images and containers running with that remap setting will reside in `/var/lib/docker/10000.10000`.
>   If you use the experimental build but don’t provide user namespace remapping, your current content will be migrated to `/var/lib/docker/0.0` to differentiate it from remapped layer content.

Update February 2016:

As noted in the comments by [Phil E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406418/phil-e)

> As of this past week, Docker 1.10 was released, and **[user namespaces was included as a feature](http://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-engine-1-10-security/)**.
>   A quick note that because of the graduation from experimental to master, the [documentation now resides in the daemon command-line reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-user-namespace-options:ee90f49520f49f91517c72cf11ab0ded).

Comment: Yes, I've been following Phil's & others work on this issue closely. Demoing this here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-25AQk3M6ic. I'm marking this as the answer, as I think this has evolved substantially since I asked this question.

Comment: @AmosFolarin Thank you. It has evolved indeed. Docker 1.10 should have that feature officially.

Comment: As of this past week, Docker 1.10 was released, and user namespaces [**was** included as a feature](http://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-engine-1-10-security/). A quick note that because of the graduation from experimental to master, the documentation now resides in the [daemon command-line reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-user-namespace-options:ee90f49520f49f91517c72cf11ab0ded) page.

Comment: @PhilE Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much:

- [Allow the docker daemon to run as non-root on the host system](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2919)
- [Having non-root privileges on the host and root inside the container](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2918)

Comment: Hmm.. Waiting on kernel user namespace, I guess this will only be supported in more recent kernels >3.10 ?